# REPLACE query does not replace all of the mentioned characters

Tags: mysql, replace, special-characters, caret

I would like to write a query which using function concat / replace, change the title of a book into a jpg filename assigned to that book.
In the book title I have some special characters.

1. all of the special characters should be changed into -
2. white space should be deleted
3. If there are next to each other two special characters (like: ," in the example below) they merge into one character -

For instance:
The book name: M. Mitchell,"Gone with the wind"
the filename is: m-mitchell-gonewiththewind.jpg

Query:

```
select *
REPLACE (REPLACE (REPLACE (REPLACE (REPLACE 
' ', ''),  /*white space - ok */
'„', '-'), /*quotation - ok */
'”', '-'), /*quotation - ok */
' \' ', '-'), /* apostrophe - ok */
 ' " ', '-') /*here is the problem*/
from ...
```

Problems:

1. AD 1

   - " changes into "
   - \" changes also into "
2. AD 3 Should I add new query into another column? Or use IF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For .. The book name: `M. Mitchell,"Gone with the wind"` the filename is: `m-mitchell-gonewiththewind.jpg`

Your query did not fail on the example. Your example did not have characters `'„'`, `'”'` and sequence of characters as `' " '`. And hence query did not result as you expected.

Change the query as below:

```
select 
  t,
  replace(
    replace( 
      trim( 
        replace( 
          replace( 
            replace( 
              replace( 
                replace( t, '.', ' ' ), -- replaces all dots
                ',', ' ' ), -- replaces all commas
              '„', ' ' ), -- replaces all „s
            '”', ' ' ), -- replaces all ”s
          '"', ' ' )  -- replaces all "s
      ), -- removes trailing spaces
      ' ', '-' ), -- replaces all space chars
    '--', '-' ) -- replaces all repeated hyphen -s
  as title
from ( select 'M. Mitchell,"Gone with the wind"' t ) titles ;
```

**Demo** on [***SQL Fiddle***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/34610)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the idea

If I run your query:

```
select 
  t,
  replace(
   replace(
    replace( 
      trim( 
        replace( 
          replace( 
            replace( 
              replace( 
                replace( t, '.', ' ' ), -- replaces all dots
                ',', ' ' ), -- replaces all commas
              '„', ' ' ), -- replaces all „s
            '”', ' ' ), -- replaces all ”s
          '"', ' ' )  -- replaces all "s
      ), -- removes trailing spaces
      ' ', '-' ), -- replaces all space chars
    '--', '-' ), -- replaces all repeated hyphen -s
    '&', '')
  as title
from ( select 'M. Mitchell,"Gone with the wind & fire'' "' t ) titles ;
```

the result:
 - for & is ok
 -  for the inch sign '' remains '

If I check this query on the real data from database I still have a problem with & and ''
 - & > is changed to &
 - '' > is not changed at all  ''

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have found the solution. 
 First it is required to change the & into space and then use the trim query.

Thank you!